# How to synchronise Access database with SQL Server,changes made in access database should reflect in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, vb6, synchronization

How to synchronise **Access database with SQL Server**, so that changes made in access database should reflect in SQL server database. Provided that the front end is Vb6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way. You have to:

1. add checksum colon in every table
2. calculate checksum in Access table for new & changed records
3. update changed records (existing key, different checksum)
4. add new records (non-existing keys)

at 1. VB6 doesn't have any checksum function. At internet are tons of VB6 checksum functions, find one and implement. Data type with more bytes is better. Hint: join all values in record in a string (something like CSV) and calculate checksum for this string.

at 2. The correct way is calculate checksum in change/new record event in your application. Less correct, but possible, is calculate checksum just before synchronisation (it depends on quantity of records and so on).

Note: Great checksum function in SQL Server is fn_repl_hash_binary. The result you can convert in *uniqueidentifier* type (*number / Replication ID* in Access). In this case you should calculate checksum by SQL server via Linked server just before synchronisation.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(@whatever))
```

at 3. and 4. There are some ways, how to use mdb from SQL Server. Choose the best for you.

- [Linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) (Note you need an extra permission, see *sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1*)
- [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) and [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx)
- and, off course, process record by record in your VB6 application. Horrible way.

Comment: Seems to be very big procedure. Is that any other option or is there any paid softwares to do the same?

Comment: Yes, it is a big procedure. I've written similar task - but in C#, it is far easier. - I don't know about another solution; if you find any, tell me. - The only correct solution is to switch from Access to SQL Server (but not Express edition) and use built-in replication features. But it is a big jump.

Comment: Since checksum calculation is the responsibility of the client anyway (i.e. not updated/calculated by the database itself upon record updates) and that **synchronization is one-way** (requirement for what's following), I would opt for a simple timestamp field (or rowversion), or else a custom field updated through an update trigger. If sync is **bi-directional**, then there's no easy solution since he'll have to deal with conflicts anyway (a checksum won't tell him which way the conflict should be resolved)

Comment: ok..Can i get a code snippet or can you suggest me site having a tutorial?

Comment: IMHO it is not possible to write a code snippet, because it is pretty complex task. But at the end it is not so much code, as it seems to be. - Using time stamp is easier (no checksum algorithm), but you have to guarantee update of time stamp in your application (it could be easy or difficult, it depends on your application); it solves steps 1 and 2 in my list above. Steps 3 and 4 are the same - link databases, add/update records.